# Reading an Excel file with C# causes OleDbException to be thrown

Tags: c#, excel

The message says

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
>   'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and
>   the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check
>   your network connection or contact the server administrator.

The name of the sheet in the Worksheet is "Sheet1"

```
        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";", fileName);
        string query = String.Format("SELECT [columnName1],[columnName2],[columnName3] from [{0}]", "Sheet1$");
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        DataTable YourTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
        listBox1.DataSource = YourTable.Columns["ColumnName1"];
```

Comment: It would probably help if you posted some code.

Comment: Assuming a Sheet1$ exists in your Excel file then there is something wrong in your connection string

Comment: The error is trying to tell you that there is no "Sheet1$" in the workbook.

Comment: Yes. The error occurs at dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

Comment: Use excel 8 not 12 `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";", fileName);`

Comment: ACtually on second look youhave a bad connectino string to many `"` Try this `String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";", fileName);`

Comment: I got the string from ConnectionStrings.com

Comment: @user2140261 you should type your answer in the answer section. But I get the same message when substituting your string with my string. It's referencing Sheet1$

Comment: all connection strings on http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel seem to agree with me. Posted an answer with code that worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
string filename = @"C:\Book1.xlsm";

        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";", filename);
        string query = String.Format("SELECT * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        DataTable YourTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

***NOTE: *** If your data does not have headers to make `HDR=NO`

Also noticed that in your question you used

```
[columnName1],[columnName2],[columnName3]
```

for your columns to select. Please remember these should be the value(s) of the first cell in the column(s) that you would like to grab.

To get column E Use:

```
        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO\";", filename);
        string query = String.Format("SELECT [F5] from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");
```

Replace 5 With any other column number you need so

```
F1 = A
F2 = B
F3 = C
```

and so on.

The Error you are getting could be because you have the file open and active.

OR you are pointing at the wrong file (Remember you have to include full file path in the `filename` string. and make sure the sheet is correct. Alos take notice to the fact the i include the `$` in my string not in my parameter so rememer to only put just the name of the sheet you are trying to get. If you are still having trouble supply me with the FULL file name for the worksheet you are using i.e. `C:\Book1.xlsm` and the sheet you are trying to get data from.

Comment: I need Column E (no header) But I'm still struggling to open the file. Your code is now throwing another exception. saying "Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only."

Comment: Edited my answer. IN order to try and fulfill your needs.

Comment: The file is definitely not open or active. Ive closed all instances of Excel and I've modified the Connection String to say READONLY=False

Comment: The problem is a new "question" since people don't like to have all problems in 1 question. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109609/oledbexception-being-thrown-at-adp-fill-saying-could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: That link is no longer applicable to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please put square brackets around Sheet1.
So your query is: select * from [Sheet1$]

Comment: The square brackets are in the `String.Format(...)` call.