# OleDbException being thrown at adp.Fill saying "Could not find installable ISAM."

Tags: c#, excel

```
        string fileName = "e:\\investigation\\report.xlsx";
        string SHEETNAME_HERE = "Sheet1";
        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";", fileName);
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
        stbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [" + SHEETNAME_HERE + "]");
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), con);

        DataSet dsXLS = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(dsXLS);
```

I am using Windows 64-bit and Office 2010 (32-bit) is Could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: Is your compiler targeting x86?

Comment: Funny you asked. Im not sure. I think its Any CPU. but I'm trying to figure out how to change it for 32-bit. I saw a forum post suggesting to try 32-bit compiling

Comment: You made a lot of changes from the code I originally gave you on [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107429/reading-an-excel-file-with-c-sharp-causes-oledbexception-to-be-thrown/16109165?noredirect=1#comment23005221_16109165)

Comment: Its the same code. Names of the variable changed.

Comment: to start the Sheet name is missing the trailing `$` the connection is using a different provider,

Comment: same error. I found this article and the registry keys don't exist. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805

Comment: I changed it to the one that you provided and it gives a NEW message. "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Comment: MAke sure you have security privileges to access the file

Comment: to access the Excel file?. I do because I can open it with Excel. I can read, write to the file too

Comment: is E a shared drive/network drive? If so try to copy the excel file to the local drive and point the c# to the new locatin and see what happens.

Comment: E is a USB drive (HDD).

Comment: Try to copy the file t the root of the C drive(or your local hard drive) and try to access it and see if it works the problem might have something to do with accessing it over USB, but I am stumped. But at least trying it from a local drive will help point us in the correct direction.

Comment: I think my [question][1] can help you...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949326/could-not-find-installable-isam-while-filling-data-in-dataset

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify the correct DLL is installed. IE Msexcl40.dll

see (ignore it says access 2k and follow the steps for resolving)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805